# How to make custom swagger documentation for my request body

Tags: kotlin, micronaut

This is my user authentication function that I am calling

```
override fun authenticate(httpRequest: HttpRequest<*>?, authenticationRequest: AuthenticationRequest<*, *>): Publisher<AuthenticationResponse> {
```

My swagger documentation looks like this

```
{
  "authenticationRequest": {
    "identity": {},
    "secret": {}
  }
}
```

But I want it to look like this

```
{
  "authenticationRequest": {
    "email": {},
    "password": {}
  }
}
```

I do not want to change the class type which is AuthenticationRequest<*, *>.

Is there any special annotation or any other method to achieve it?